# Asp.net MVC Many to Many Junction Table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My `dbContext` always returns null for my junction table. Can I solve the problem by not changing the DB relationship design?

**My problem**

[image]

I want just `Id = 1` and `Stationery_Id = 1` and `UOM_Id = 1`

Here is all the detail information...

**Database Design**

[image: Database design]

**Class**

[image]

**Data in my db**

[image]

Comment: Have you implemented the relationships in your code?

Comment: @Hadi That all my codes.. I don’t know how to do it.

Comment: Check this: [https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx)

Comment: @Hadi Thank for your support bro. I used model first approach. I can't update `dbContext` and `model class` manually I think. Debug never reach to `onModelCreating`

Comment: @Hadi I found `Model first approch` never execute `onModelCreating`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876586/ef-4-1-onmodelcreating-not-called

Comment: @Hadi Thanks I changed connection string and it executed `onModelCreating` and works. But is there any problem to my `Model First Approach`? I am new to this asp.net MVC

Comment: Isn't it related to lazy loading ?! try using `Include`.

follow https://entityframework.net/when-to-use-include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's related to `lazy loading`. As this [tutorial](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx) said:

> Lazy loading is `delaying` the loading of related data until you specifically request for it

You never ever request related data directly in this code snippet, so the expectation of loading related data is wrong.

If you wanna load related data at the moment, you can use `Include` to achieve that:

```
db.StockUOMs.Include(i => i.UOM).Include(i => i.Stationery).ToList();
```

for a deep dive, you can follow this [link](https://entityframework.net/when-to-use-include).

good luck.